# Jquery window.print() not printing plain text content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have integrated webmail in my laravel web app.
[image]

Now here some of the mails in inbox is plain text and some of them are html.

1) plain text mail
[image]

2) Html mail
[image]

Now When I am opening mail to read, there is print button . When I click on print button my mail should be printed so I have written jquery code like this.

```
$("[id=print]").click(function(e)
    {
      w=window.open();
      w.document.write($('#readmailcontainer').html());
      w.print();
      w.close();
    });
```

Now when I print HTML mail I get proper print preview like this

[image]

But when I print plain text mail , then I get blanck page

[image]

I know that i am using .html() in jquery code to get html , so I am getting proper html content, but I should also get plain text using .html() but it is showing nothing there .

I logged output in console and I see that for plain text it is returning complete html code , If i use .text() then it only shows plain text for both the mails.

I am not sure how can this be done.

**OuterHtml for #readmailcontainer for plain text**

```
<div class="col-md-9" id="readmailcontainer" style="display: block;">
              <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                  <h3 class="box-title" id="fromname">SANIERP</h3>
                  <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Back" id="backtomailbox"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrow-circle-left" style="font-size: 20px"></i></a>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body no-padding">
                  <div class="mailbox-read-info">
                    <h3 id="subject"></h3>
                    <h5 id="fromaddress">From : erp@saniservice.com<span class="mailbox-read-time pull-right">2017-07-05 04:11:42</span></h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mailbox-controls with-border text-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                      <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Reply"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></button>
                      <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Forward"><i class="fa fa-share"></i></button>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" id="print" data-original-title="Print"><i class="fa fa-print"></i></button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mailbox-read-message" id="mailbody">



    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
    <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->




<p>hello vijay</p>


    <br><br><br><br>



</div>
                </div>


                <div class="box-footer">
                  <ul class="mailbox-attachments clearfix" id="attachment"></ul>
                </div>


                <div class="box-footer">
                  <div class="pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Reply</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Forward</button>
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: It's working OK for me: https://jsfiddle.net/n4qgtj0a/. Can you provide the outerHTML of the `#readmailcontainer` element?

Comment: @james updated outerhtml in question